# NestJS Database and Storage HealthChecks dont work together

Tags: nestjs

I am trying to setup a health check for my nest.js server and somehow the out of the box storage health check and database health check work individually but not together: My code reduced to the relevant smaple is this:

```
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import { HealthCheckService, HttpHealthIndicator, HealthCheck, TypeOrmHealthIndicator, MemoryHealthIndicator, DiskHealthIndicator } from '@nestjs/terminus';
import { SurfaceHealthIndicator } from './surface.health';

@Controller('health')
export class HealthController {
   constructor(
      private health: HealthCheckService,
      private http: HttpHealthIndicator,
      private db: TypeOrmHealthIndicator,
      private memory: MemoryHealthIndicator,
      private disk: DiskHealthIndicator,
      private surface: SurfaceHealthIndicator

   ) { }

   @Get()
   @HealthCheck()
   check() {
      return this.health.check([
         () => this.db.pingCheck('database'),
         () => this.disk.checkStorage('storage', {
            path: 'C:\\',
            thresholdPercent: 0.95
         }),
      ]);
   }
}
```

That leads to Health Check has failed! {"storage":{"status":"up"},"database":{"status":"down","message":"timeout of 1000ms exceeded"}}'

However the db is up (I checked ) and when I take out the storage health check however I get

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "info": {
    "database": {
      "status": "up"
    }
  },
  "error": {},
  "details": {
    "database": {
      "status": "up"
    }
  }
}
```

And similarly when I remove the db heath check I get

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "info": {
    "storage": {
      "status": "up"
    }
  },
  "error": {},
  "details": {
    "storage": {
      "status": "up"
    }
  }
}
```

So I wonder what's wrong. Any ideas someone? Also if I use db, memory, http and custom health checks together everything works nicely. It seems to really be the combination of db and storage health check. ideas?

Cheers
Tom

Comment: We are running into the exact same issue. We have confirmed that the database is up. It is actually the failed healthcheck call in our ECS containers that is causing tasks to be drained, and new instances take a while to come up. This cascading effect brings our API to a standstill. I would also love some suggestions on how to handle this.